# How to register a SIP account in xlite Softphone?

Tags: c#, sip, pbx

I am trying to build a SIP PBX in c#. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/739075/How-to-build-a-simple-SIP-PBX-in-Csharp-extended). But I am stuck after doing the first part of the tutorial. Where I run the application for the first time and I get the following console window.

[image: console]

Now I am supposed to use the xlite Softphone to register a SIP account? But for the life of me, I can't figure out what I am supposed to enter in the "Account Settings" window from xlite Softphone Software.

[image]

I mean what is `Domain`, `Password`, `User ID`, `Authorization Name` and all the other fields? I am new to this whole subject and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect to the application. I just used the following settings if anyone might be interested. Here `A` in `User ID` is just a random letter I selected. It has no connection to the code or any of the settings. `Domain` is the same as the IP shown on my console window. `Display Name` again a random name. `Authorization Name` is the same as `User ID`. Leave the rest as it is.

[image]